# How to use dropdownmenu with sharedpref in flutter

Tags: flutter

I tried to use dropdownbutton, to select a text in a menu and display it. After I send sms with the selected text. to finish I  tried to save the value with sharedpref to display text after app close. To this I upload sharedpref in the init state. But I have an error :

```
     failed assertion line 481 pos 15: value==null||items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> 
     item) => item.value == value).length == 1: is not true.
```

Here is my dropdownbutton block:

```
                                      new DropdownButton<String>(

                                        onChanged: (String changedValue) {
                                          selectedText=changedValue;
                                          setState(() {
                                            selectedText;

                                          });
                                        },
                                        value: selectedText,
                                        items: <String>['1', '2', '3','4', '5', '6','7', '8', '9']
                                            .map((String value) {
                                          return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                            value: value,
                                            child: new Text(value),
                                          );
                                        }).toList()),
```

Here is my sharedpref block :

```
 _savevaluesonnerie() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      setState(() {
      prefs.setString('counter305', selectedText);
     });
   } 


  _loadvaluesonnerie() async {
     SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      setState(() {
      selectedText = (prefs.getString('counter305')) ??"" ;
   });
   }
```

I call this sharedpref block in an Initstate to display the saved value

```
 @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();

   _loadvaluesonnerie();
  }
```

Thank you

Comment: Where are you calling `_savevaluesonnerie` function() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using **async** function `_loadvaluesonnerie()` to set the `selectedText`, until it finishes, `selectedText` will be null.

Can you set some **default** value like `'1'` (which is first item in items) as initial value for `selectedText`?

Will that work for you?

Comment: it's OK thank you. It's not a perfect solution for me but it's work,